# Подставить в адресную строку то, что ввёл в input

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы пользователь ввёл в [input type="text"] число, к примеру, 200, нажал на кнопку перейти и перешёл бы на страницу вида `site.ru/go.php?id=200`.

Как такое сообразить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил сам.

```
<input id="text" type="text"/> <input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://site.ru/'+document.getElementById('text').value"/>
```